# Python3, ordering a complex dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a complex Python dictionary that stores the following values:
MAC ADDRESS, RSSI and TIMESTAMP:

```
beacons_detected = {
    '55:c1:9a:41:4c:b9': ['-78', '1493580469'],
    '9c:20:7b:e0:6c:41': ['-74', '1493622425'],
    '5e:30:e7:12:97:64': ['-79', '1493587968']
}
```

I would like to order that list based on timestamp... any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sort the dictionary from smallest to largest:

```
>>> sorted(beacons_detected.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
[('55:c1:9a:41:4c:b9', ['-78', '1493580469']), ('5e:30:e7:12:97:64', ['-79', '1493587968']), ('9c:20:7b:e0:6c:41', ['-74', '1493622425'])]
```

sort the dictionary from largest to smallest:

```
>>> sorted(beacons_detected.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
[('9c:20:7b:e0:6c:41', ['-74', '1493622425']), ('5e:30:e7:12:97:64', ['-79', '1493587968']), ('55:c1:9a:41:4c:b9', ['-78', '1493580469'])]
```

Comment: Theoretically we want `int(x[1][1])` though the odds that this matter are practically zero.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, you are right but in this case the `timestamp` is already a `str`, hence string comparison would be much faster rather than converting them into a int and doing comparison since conversion is a costly matter.

Comment: Right, merely pointing out that the comparison is only correct since the all the values have the same number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sorted dictionary, then use the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
>>> ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(beacons_detected.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))
OrderedDict([('55:c1:9a:41:4c:b9', ['-78', '1493580469']),
             ('5e:30:e7:12:97:64', ['-79', '1493587968']),
             ('9c:20:7b:e0:6c:41', ['-74', '1493622425'])])
```

And the access is same as `dict`:

```
>>> ordered['55:c1:9a:41:4c:b9']
['-78', '1493580469']
```